# C# WPF how to set an item in a listbox made of a list of object in a datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

C# - WPF
I have a listbox ("lstCustomer") popolated with a List of "Id_Name" objects

From a point of the code i obtain an ID - for example "2"
How can I select programmatically the element of the listBox with 2 as ID ?

lstCustomer.SelectedIndex = ????

CODE - POPOLATE THE LIST

```
List<Id_Name> list = new ();
list.Add(new Id_Name { Id = "1" , Name = "John" });
list.Add(new Id_Name { Id = "2", Name = "Jim" });
list.Add(new Id_Name { Id = "3", Name = "Frank" });
lstCustomer.ItemsSource = list;
```

XAML - LISTBOX and DATATEMPLATE

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstCustomer"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Id_Name_Template}" />


<DataTemplate  x:Key="Id_Name_Template">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
                            <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Set `SelectedValuePath="Id"` on the ListBox, and `lstCustomer.SelectedValue = "2";` to select Jim.

Comment: `<ListBox x:Name="custList"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplatePath}"
         SelectedValuePath="Id"
         SelectedValue="{Binding Id}"/>`                                                                                                 **in your view model**
`public string Id{ get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not hell bent on using the index i'd suggest binding the SelectedItem property of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstCustomer"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Id_Name_Template}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedId_Name}"/>
```

and then in your ViewModel you can just set that property:

```
public Id_Name SelectedId_Name { get; set; }   //Needs to call your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged   

[...]  
SelectedId_Name = list.Where( x => x.Id == "2").FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Or make use of the ListBox's built-in `SelectedValue` feature:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstCustomer"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Id_Name_Template}"
         SelectedValuePath="Id"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"/>
```

with

```
public string SelectedId { get; set; } // plus notification

[...]
SelectedId = "2";
```